# specifying mainClass for scala.js?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, scala.js

I was doing this tutorial on scala.js in a project with two other main classes already: https://www.scala-js.org/doc/tutorial/basic/index.html

In my build.sbt file, I had written this line of code.

```
scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true
```

Then, I got this error:

```
[error] (Compile / scalaJSModuleInitializers) No main module initializer was specified (possibly because no or multiple main classes were found), but scalaJSUseMainModuleIni
tializer was set to true. You can explicitly specify it either with `mainClass := Some(...)` or with `scalaJSMainModuleInitializer := Some(...)`
```

I'm trying to specify the main class, or to get it to compile using the second option (scalaJSMainModuleInitializer := Some(...)).

The folder of the main class is in src/main/scala/scalaJSclasses/webapp, the main class is called App, and the main method is called main.

what goes in the (...)??

I've tried

```
mainClass := Some("src/main/scala/scalaJSclasses.webapp.App.main")
mainClass := Some("src/main/scala/scalaJSclasses.webapp.App")
```

and

```
scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := mainMethod("scalaJSclasses.webapp.App.Main", "main")
```

I guess I just need help with figuring out how it read the path to the file. Please help.

Comment: Can you share your main?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to specify a file path to the class you want to use.

Try this instead

```
mainClass := Some("scalaJSclasses.webapp.App")
```